# How to enable WSS for Websocket ServerEndpoint on Glassfish Server?

Tags: websocket, glassfish

Where can I find a good tutorial on enabling SSL/WSS for my glassfish websocket server endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

You can start with echo-https tyrus [sample](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/glassfish/tyrus/samples/tyrus-sample-echo-https/1.7/tyrus-sample-echo-https-1.7-project-src.zip).

(please see README.html in the archive).

Comment: The echo server in the sample relies on deployment as a war, but we're using Jax-RS microservices and programmatically starting Grizzly/Tyrus/Spring ourselves. Securing the websockets with SSL/TLS is the last step in proving our new architecture. All help gratefully received!