# Websocket over wss in context of Spring + Angular + Tyrus

Tags: angular, spring, websocket, tyrus

Following situation:

I have Spring-Boot-backend which communicates with an angular frontend.
They are both packaged together into an executable *war*.

Until recently it used *http* and *ws*. Now I want to migrate to using *https* and *wss*.

The transition to *https* worked just fine and the flow of events goes well for the combination of *https* and *ws*.

This is my (shortened) function on the angular side triggering the connection upgrade:

```
upgradeConnectionToWS() {
    const app = this;
    return new Promise<WebSocket>(function (resolve, reject) {

        let socket: WebSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8025/ws/notify");

        socket.onopen = function (event) {
            [...]
            resolve(socket);
        };

        [...onmessage, onerror,...]
    });
}
```

My ServerEndpoint (shortened):

```
    @javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint(
        value = "/notify",
        encoders = JsonMessageEncoder.class,
        decoders = JsonMessageDecoder.class,
        configurator = WSEndpointConfigurator.class
    )
    public class WsServerEndpoint{
   
        @OnOpen
        public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config) {
            System.out.println(format("%s initiated ws-connection.", session.getId()));
            [...logging stuff, pushing variables...]
        }
    }
```

The WsEndpointConfigurer mainly logs Headers.

My Main looks like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server server = 
            new org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server("localhost", 8025, "/ws", WsServerEndpoint.class);
        try {
            server.start();
        } catch (DeploymentException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Relevant dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
        <artifactId>tyrus-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
        <artifactId>tyrus-container-grizzly</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now when I switch to wss in the angular part I only get timeouts on the upgrade-requests.

So far this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53867046
was one of the few things I found on the subject but it wasn't helpful to me to be honest.

I would be thankful for any help. If there is more information needed, I will try to provide it.